# Rust TcpStream can't be written after reading, but can be written without reading. Why?

Tags: rust

See the below code.

```
fn listen() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:3000").unwrap();
    
    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        let mut stream = stream.unwrap();
        let mut data_buf = Vec::new();

        stream.read_to_end(&mut data_buf).unwrap(); // Stream read
            
        println!("{}", String::from_utf8(data_buf).unwrap());

        stream.write_all(get_http_response().as_bytes()).unwrap();
    }
}

fn get_http_response() -> String {
    let status_line = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK";
    let contents = "<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang=\"en\">
      <head>
        <meta charset=\"utf-8\">
        <title>Poda thendi!</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Poda thendi!</h1>
        <p>Hi from Rust</p>
      </body>
    </html>";
    let length = contents.len();

    format!("{status_line}\r\nContent-Length: {length}\r\n\r\n{contents}")
}
```

Now, if I visit 127.0.0.1:3000 on a browser, it shows a pending state.

But if I remove the "Stream read" line, it works just as expected. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> stream.read_to_end(...)
> ```

`read_to_end` expects the browser to close the connection (or at least shutdown for writing) after the request is finished. Because there is no other kind of signaling "end" for a TCP connection than to shutdown for writing (i.e. sending FIN).

But, the browser will not close/shutdown the connection after the request. Instead it will be kept open to read the response and maybe send more requests over the same TCP connection. That's why it will simply hang there in your code and never reach the part where it can write the answer. And the browser will therefore hang around too, since it never gets the response.

Instead of using `read_to_end` you need to actually read the data in chunks and parse these to detect the end of the request. For this you need to understand the message format of HTTP - see [the standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-3).